# How to take input after getline

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    int ID;
    long phno;
    string name;
    string depart;
    string email;
};

int main ()
{
    Student S1 ;

    cout << "\n=======================================================\n" ;

    cout << "Enter ID no. of student 1       : " ; cin >> S1.ID ;
    cout << "Enter name of student 1         : " ; getline(cin, S1.name) ; cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter department of student 1   : " ; getline(cin, S1.depart) ; cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter email adress of student 1 : " ; getline(cin, S1.email) ; cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter phone number of student 1 : " ; cin >> S1.phno ;     

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that it's not taking input after email adress the program is ignoring to take input in phno, directly exit after emailadress.

Comment: Why are you calling `cin.ignore();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some slight modifications to your code.

Note that I *only* call `cin.ignore()` after I use `cin` directly on a variable (`cin >> S1.ID` or `cin >> S1.phno`).

This is because when you use `cin` on an int, it leaves the `\n` in the buffer. When you later call `getline(cin,...)` you just suck up that leftover `\n`, and that's considered your whole "line."

A working example is available [here](https://ideone.com/veGLlB).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
    int ID;
    long phno;
    string name;
    string depart;
    string email;
};

int main ()
{
    Student S1 ;

    cout << "\n=======================================================\n" ;

    cout << "Enter ID no. of student 1       :\n" ;
    cin >> S1.ID ; 
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter name of student 1         :\n" ;
    getline(cin, S1.name) ; 

    cout << "Enter department of student 1   :\n" ;
    getline(cin, S1.depart) ;

    cout << "Enter phone number of student 1 :\n" ;
    cin >> S1.phno ;
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter email adress of student 1 :\n" ;
    getline(cin, S1.email) ;    

    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << S1.ID << endl << S1.name << endl << S1.depart << endl << S1.phno << endl << S1.email << endl;

    return 0;
}
```